# Core Data Saving Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios4

I'm trying to save some data to core data from a different view and I keep getting a error when I press the button to save the data. The that I get is:

```
Unresolved error (null), (null)
```

Here's all my code:

SomeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class NameData;
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
    NameData *nameData;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NameData *nameData;

- (IBAction)saveData;

@end
```

SomeViewController.m

```
#import "SomeViewController.h"
#import  "NameData"

@implementation SomeViewController

@synthesize addTeam;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Add Name;

}

- (IBAction)saveData{

    NSString *string = @"demo";

    nameData.nameContent = string;
    nameData.name2Content = string;
    nameData.name3Content = string;


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![nameData.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();  // Fail
    }   
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [nameData release];
}
@end
```

NameData.h

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface NameData :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nameContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name2Content;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name3Content;
@end
```

NameData.m

```
#import "NameData"

@implementation NameData

@dynamic nameContent;
@dynamic name2Content;
@dynamic name3Content;
@end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show what the error is.

Comment: Indeed. Change your NSLog to this: `NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);`.

Comment: It's up at very top: Error is "Unresolved error (null), (null)" and the app shuts down.

Comment: @lxt, I change it to what you said and I still get the same error: Unresolved error (null), (null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save should be performed on the managedObjectContext instance, not the model itself.

Example:

```
NSError *error;
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
if (![moc save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@ - %@", 
          [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: When using your code, the app crashes without any error from debugger. Humm.... idk why it's doing that.

Comment: The posted code snippet wasn't meant to be a copy/paste solution.  In your code you are accessing the managedObjectContext class through your namedData instance.  Normally the managedObjectContext is accessed through the controller, as was shown in my example. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: It's actually safer to do it on the namedData's managedObjectContext reference, because it could (unlikely, but possibly) be a different context than the one used for the fetchedResultsController.